# IOS status bar LigthContent

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift

I tried change style for IOS app. With follow mehods.

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().setStatusBarStyle(UIStatusBarStyle.LightContent, animated: false)
application.statusBarStyle = UIStatusBarStyle.LightContent
```

And

[image: Xcode setting config]

But i have result with default style:

[image: Result]

How to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to Info tab of the project target, Add Row:

`UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance`, set value `NO`

and set the status bar in Deployment Info to Light

should works

Comment: Thanks! It's resolve my issue!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your info.plist is also not setting the status bar style...
There are three values you can choose in the status bar style value try accordingly. And make sure that the status bar is not view controller based.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

i think you need to add  View controller-based status bar appearance in your plist file. This image shows that.[It shows were to add lines of codes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CTedL.png)